# is there a easy way to align subviews?

Tags: swiftui

my code is like the following, I want the four images aligned to 2*5, alignmentGuider works here, while, is there an easier way can get the same result?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      
        ForEach(0..<10id:\.self){ _ in
        Image(systemName: "star")
        .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100,height: 150)
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "aligned to 2*5"?

Comment: 10 subviews in a column default, I want 10 subviews displayed in 2 columns, each column has 5 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a ScrollView(.horizontal) instead, it is more conform to SwiftUI's design maybe.